# Redis + How long redis set key to server and commit

Tags: redis

I would like to measure the time elapsed from when a Redis `set` command is issued to when the server actually commits the key.

Is there a way to measure this?

Comment: Can you fix the grammar and add more description? I can't understand the question.

Comment: ex: when i send comand **set**  aaaa to redis server then how long server commit this key ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to measure the time taken for a server commit. I have used Redis and its generally fast unless there is any issue with latency. Is this to address a performance issue or specific to any other? @QuyAnh

Comment: My company use 4 nodes redis about ( 3 slave + 1 master with structure automatic failover) but sometime slave disconnect to master, i set quorum = 3, i dont know a reason slave disconnect to master via sentinel.

Comment: How does knowing commit time answers your question? If you have AOF on, you can `tail` to it and see when the key is committed. Maybe this will help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

INFO command of redis will list the statistics you are looking for in particular the command **INFO Stats** got **instantaneous_ops_per_sec** which are the number of commands processed by redis in last second.

This will help you in estimating time taken by Redis Instance for your operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are many parts of processing a command. First, you send it from client to server over the wire, then TCP worker on the server reads client buffer, processes a message and puts it in command queue, then eventually Redis main loop pops the command from queue, processes it *(when this part ends, the key is commited)*, then writes the answer in a client buffer, then eventually TCP worker finds that there is an answer ready and sends it to the client over the wire. In 99% cases sending over the wire is where you spend most of the time.

The metric you suggested - from issuing a command to key being committed is hard to measure, just because these events take place on different sides. But more importantly, you don't have to measure it. The two main metrics being measured in such systems are:

- latency (from sending a command to receiving an answer)
- throughput (how much commands from different clients can server process in a time interval, usually in a second)

If for some reason you insist on measuring it, you may do the following:

1. Ensure server and client machines time is perfectly synced. Redis is fast, so the scale may go for nanos even.
2. before call save current time in a client (e.g. `long start = System.nanoTime();` in Java)
3. Call not set, but lua script: `eval "redis.call('set','my_key','3,1415') return redis.call('time')" 0`
4. On the client, substract start time from the time you recieved as an answer. You will need to handle difference in output formats, Redis gives microsecond precision.
5. Do this many times to get stable results. You will get *a slower result*, because some time would be spent on lua scripting and even on measuring time.